# Can a contract really get stuck?

Tags: solidity

I was reading Solidity's docs and found this:

```
// Forward the delegation as long as
// `to` also delegated.
// In general, such loops are very dangerous,
// because if they run too long, they might
// need more gas than is available in a block.
// In this case, the delegation will not be executed,
// but in other situations, such loops might
// cause a contract to get "stuck" completely.
```

I thought that infinite loops would just consume the gas and revert all the transactions. How can a contract *get "stuck" completely*?

Answer (score 2):

"stuck" here means that nothing after the loop will ever get executed because regardless of how much gas you send the method call will go out of gas.

It is similar to throwing on the first line of a method definition - nothing after it can ever be executed. It is "stuck" in the sense that the remainder of the function definition is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

There's the classical mistake https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4ghzhv/governmentals_1100_eth_jackpot_payout_is_stuck/.

The winner of the jackpot has to pay for clearing the contract internal storage but to do so it will need more gas than the block limit, so the transaction will always fail. And the prize was locked inside the contract.

Eventually the block limit has raised enough to claim the prize.